# Is there an easy-to-use, all-encompassing table package?

Tags: tables

I've been frustrated in recent applications with designing tables in LaTeX that have the properties I desire. I can almost always achieve the formatting I want, but a large part of my frustration comes from the fact that *every formatting change is ad-hoc or appears like a hack*. I am not a fan of this style of LaTeX design.

I was wondering if there is a *single* package that allows me to create a table environment with the following properties:

1. I can specify the horizontal and vertical alignments of every row and column, individually.
2. I can specify the height and width of every row and column, individually, either in terms of fixed lengths or stretching.
3. Failing to specify one of the above yields a pleasing default behavior similar to the default tabular settings.
4. The table is capable of spanning multiple pages without breaking.

The ideal formatting for me would be one for which, at the beginning of the environment, one can declare all the relevant spacing and alignment parameters for both rows and columns, and then the body of the table follows. Note that in the default tabular environment, this is true *only* of the columns; the formatting for each row appears in the body.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I like the emphasis `...................`

Comment: Haha, well, is there anything that can just do the first two? I recognize the difficulties in designing table environments that can work across multiple pages.

Comment: @azetina not so much emphasis, just obeying the site rules:-)

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong page breaking isn't so hard (if you don't want page break mid-cell) but the first two are hard, mostly hard to think of a good syntax. Just how do you envisage specifying _row_ setting at the start. Columns work as there are a fixed number of columns but there are an unspecified number of rows.

Comment: I suppose that one is so used to using a word processor and forgets that LaTeX is a little bit different. Certain things just require specific details and until someone clever like @DavidCarlisle invents such a wheel then one would need to customize.

Comment: I would specify rows in a syntax nearly identical to the column settings in tabular. Just as trying to make more columns than are specified (using too many &'s) breaks the output, specifying too many rows would do the same thing.

Comment: @azetina I've never used a word processor (other than using it as a reader if someone sends me such a document:-)

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong a fixed number of rows would be possible but is alien to the underlying TeX mechanisms so you'd have to code almost the whole thing "by hand" without any help from the underlying `\halign` tex table primitive. (That's not necessarily a bad idea, not using `\halign` has been proposed several times for various reasons) I'm not sure it's that friendly though to envisage a multipage many row table but you have to specify in advance the formatting of row 12016

Comment: @David, I understand that the implementation would not be the easiest but I guess I was hoping that somebody might have stepped up and tried to make something towards this direction. I wasn't expecting that all my wishes would come true. To address your last comment, however, I don't think that specifying the formatting of a row in advance is fundamentally more restrictive than specifying the formatting of a column in advance.

Comment: have you looked at the `pgfplotstable` package?

Comment: The `\abovebaseline` and `\belowbaseline` macros of `stackengine` package are similar to `\raisebox`, but place an object relative to the baseline, rather than move it relative to its current location.  I have found it helpful for adjusting the vertical placement of entries in a tabular row.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The One And Only Tabular Layout Package

You are asking for a package to improve the way to lay out your tabulars. On the German list TEX-D-L recently somebody required help to display data in a special way, depending whether the integer inside a cell differs from a standard value and [Herbert Voss](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2478/herbert) came up with a very nice and short solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,xcolor}
\def\stripCmd\ignorespaces#1\unskip{#1}
\def\checkVal#1!!{\def\temp{\stripCmd#1}%
   \ifnum\temp>3\textcolor{red}{#1}\else%
     \ifnum\temp<3\textcolor{blue}{#1}\else#1\fi\fi}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} *5{>{\checkVal}c<{!!}} c @{}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &\\
7 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 3 & \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Tabular with coloured values]

Nice, isn't it?

People need very different layouts inside tabulars. They vary much more than the layout of ordinary text does.

So the package that serves your needs won't help others much. So please, give us some examples of the tabulars you'd like to create. Maybe someone here can provide some kind of shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by David Carlisle in the comments, the "normal" underlying TeX primitives for this are `\halign` and `\valign`, for horizontal alignment and vertical alignment, respectively.

They are used like this:

```
\[h|v]align{<preamble template(s)>\cr
            <content>\cr}
```

where `#` (or, character with `\catcode` 6) marks the place where the `<content>` for that column/row will go, and `&` (or, character with `\catcode` 4) divides columns/rows, both in the `<preamble>`, and in the `<content>`.

`\halign` puts the `<content>`s into `\hbox`es, while `\valign` puts them in `\vbox`es.

Unfortunately they cannot be combined (at least to my knowledge); so while with `\halign` you can define individual column templates, and with `\valign` individual row templates, you can't use them both at the same time.

So the "normal" underlying primitives fail on points 1) and 2), while 3) depends on the given `<preamble template>`.  4) should be covered, though.

If ConTeXt is an option, you could have a look at the [TABLE](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TABLE), and [other table typesetting possibilities](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Tables_Overview).

Comment: Thanks for the info about \halign and \valign. I don't think I'll be switching from basic LaTeX any time soon, however.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest my [cals](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cals) package, which support decorations by design. Although it does not fit your request completely, you might find it useful. [Examples of use.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cals/examples/demo.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

All these four properties are easy peasy with `tblr` environment in LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray).

> 1. I can specify the horizontal and vertical alignments of every row and column, individually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l]Q[c]Q[r]},rowspec={|Q[t]|Q[m]|Q[b]|}}
 {Alpha \\ Alpha} & Beta               & Gamma \\
 Delta            & Epsilon            & {Zeta \\ Zeta}  \\
 Eta              & {Theta \\ Theta}   & Iota  \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> 2. I can specify the height and width of every row and column, individually, either in terms of fixed lengths or stretching.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines,row{1-3}={7mm},column{1-4}={15mm,c}}
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   & Delta \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     & Theta \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  & Mu    \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> 3. Failing to specify one of the above yields a pleasing default behavior similar to the default tabular settings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{}
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   & Delta \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     & Theta \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  & Mu    \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

> 4. The table is capable of spanning multiple pages without breaking.

This property was added into `tabularray` package in version 2021L.